# SQL SELECT - Return boolean based on condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Essentially I'm trying to do this

```
select  u.Hostname, u.IsCustom, (u.Status = 5) as IsActive
from    SiteUrlMappings u
```

Where 5 is an int representing an "Active" url.

Of course this doesn't work, and my sql is rusty like an old screwdriver.

Comment: What should be returned if `Status IS NULL`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You don't need a CASE expression
Just leverage how `bit` works: all non-zero values give 1 when cast to bit

```
SELECT
    u.Hostname,
    u.IsCustom,
    ~ CAST((u.Status = 5) AS bit) AS IsActive
from    SiteUrlMappings u
```

Comment: @Martin Smith: I bollixed my tilde on my Swiss keyboard. Thanks

Comment: Does the tilde have special meaning?

Comment: @Ben: bitwise NOT in SQL Server (at least)

Comment: I've just leaned using the ~ to flip the result.

Answer (score 33):

SQL Server doesn't have a boolean datatype. The closest is `bit`

```
SELECT u.Hostname,
       u.IsCustom,
       CAST(CASE
              WHEN u.Status = 5 THEN 1
              ELSE 0
            END AS BIT) AS IsActive
FROM   SiteUrlMappings u
```

Comment: SQL Server is in fact [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#boolean-data-type) to have a Boolean data type. It just can not be returned from a `SELECT` or used as the type of a column or variable. For example, the type of a `WHERE` expression *has* to be Boolean, not `bit`. The `=` comparison operator returns a Boolean, for example.

The interesting thing is that the SQL Server Boolean type has three valid values: `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `UNKNOWN`.

Comment: @V.S. - yeah it uses one internally - but this is not one that is of any use to the questioner here - who is trying to *return* a boolean. Nor will you find it listed in the data types here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 - hopefully at some point they do implement an actual SQL Standard boolean datatype that can be used by us as any other datatype

Answer (score 8):

You need a `case` statement, like this:

```
select  u.Hostname,
        u.IsCustom,
        convert(bit, case when u.Status = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as IsActive

from    SiteUrlMappings u
```

`bit` is as close to true boolean as you can get in SQL Server

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    u.Hostname,
    u.IsCustom,
    CASE
WHEN u.Status = 5 THEN
    1
ELSE
    0
END AS IsActive
from    SiteUrlMappings u
```

Comment: You need to convert it to a bit. This will return an integer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CASE ... WHEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) syntax instead.