# Select value if condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In a query selection I would like to display the result whether a field satisfies a condition.

Imagine that I have a table called `stock`. This table has a column that tells me the number of each item in the stock.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
SELECT 
    stock.name, IF (stock.quantity <20, "Buy urgent", "There is enough")
FROM stock
```

Is there any function in SQL Server to do that?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try [Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

```
SELECT   stock.name,
      CASE 
         WHEN stock.quantity <20 THEN 'Buy urgent'
         ELSE 'There is enough'
      END
FROM stock
```

Comment: I'll use this but seems such a shame to have to do this when all I want is a boolean value. can't see why mssql can't let me do "select (stock.quantity <20) As booleanValue"

Comment: @JoshuaDuxbury If you want a boolean value you can try something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/7778500/2246380

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at CASE statements
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx