# Dynamically choose one of two columns based on a third column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables, lets say tables A, B, C to obfuscate my software :).
A and B have two columns with numeric values and Table C has a Boolean column.

What I want is to create a view with a single column where depending on the column in C, either the value in A or B is selected.

Example:

Input:

```
        | A.val |    | B.val |    | C.val |
        ---------    ---------    ---------
entry1  |   1   |    |   6   |    |   T   |
entry2  |   2   |    |   8   |    |   F   |
```

Output:

```
       | D |
       -----
entry1 | 1 |
entry2 | 8 |
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in a SQL statement(s) since I am currently doing it programmatically which eats up unnecessary resources.

Comment: you should show the table structures and mention the keys in those tables

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598350/select-value-if-condition-in-sql-server

Comment: vkp, The keys are "entry1", "entry2". Probably could've made that more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're trying to select A if C = T or B if C = F then you can just use a Case Statement

```
Select (Case When C.val = TRUE Then A.val Else B.Val END) AS D
From Table
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great. Don't know how I skimmed over the existence of 'CASE'

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) syntax for that.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN C.val = 'T' THEN A.val ELSE B.val END as yourField
```