# Why can't I SELECT column_name IS NULL in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

```
create table MyTable (id int not null primary key, val int);

insert into MyTable (id, val) values (1, 1), (2, null);

select id, val, val is null as val_null from MyTable;
```

Surely this is valid SQL. Yet SQL server complains of invalid syntax at the "is null". Why does this happen?

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/73f9a/1 (I tried this for SQL Server 2008 and for 2014, but for 2014 I keep getting an "Oops" message, suggesting that something is wrong with SQL Fiddle, possibly a temporary thing.)

Comment: How is that valid SQL? What are you trying to do?  `WHERE val IS NULL`?

Comment: How, specifically, would it not be valid?

Comment: That depends what you're actually trying to do, which you have not explained.

Comment: No, a WHERE clause would be totally different. I should get two rows, because I don't have a WHERE clause; one row for each table row.

Comment: I'm issuing a query without a WHERE clause, so I should get one row for each row in the table. I've listed three columns, so there should be three columns in the result set.

Comment: it´s not valid because you can´t select a boolean expression [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778444/sql-select-return-boolean-based-on-condition)

Comment: add your expected result for this data!

Comment: I think that the expected result is obvious, given any knowledge of SQL at all.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a boolean data type (in terms of being able to define columns/variables of such a type). As such, what do you expect the data type of `val_null` to be?

Comment: Well that explains why it doesn't work, although it seems completely insane to me that "SQL Server doesn't have a boolean data type".

Comment: This syntax works in the obviously sensible way in MySQL. It seems quite barmy to me that SQL Server throws a fit over it.

Comment: I don't think boolean was added to the SQL standard until '99 (or maybe '03) - either way, just because it's in a standard doesn't mean that every database system supports it. Here's the complete [list of data types for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187752.aspx)

Comment: Well, that's fine, but I don't understand how they decided it was a good idea to not just add their own boolean datatype to their implementation, instead of leaving it as some kind of pseudo-type that you can't select *and then not even issue helpful error messages if you try to do so*.

Comment: When you worked with MySQL before you will notice that some of it's syntax variations are not allowed in other DBMSes :-)

Comment: Btw, if you complain about a DBMS being *completely insane*  without boolean datatype, at least Oracle, DB2 and Teradata don't support it, too. And MySQL's `BOOLEAN` is actually a `TINYINT(1)` which uses `0` for `FALSE` and `1` for `TRUE`, but also allows any other value between `-128` and `127` (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f047/2), good luck using that crappy implementation :-)

Comment: The specifics of it that you reference aren't relevant - it has something you can select and get a sane result, which is all that's relevant here. And I'm not volunteering here to defend every design decision made by the MySQL team, nor do I intend to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write `is null` in conditions only, mssql does not support convertion from condition to boolean value. So, you need [IIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574(v=sql.120).aspx) statement to get result:

```
select id, val, IIF(val is null, 1, 0) as val_null 
from MyTable;
```

`IIF` works with SQL Server 2012+ versions.

Comment: You should add some explanations to this, why it's like that and so on, but that's the right answer...

Comment: Certainly this gives a sensible result, but it doesn't explain why my original syntax doesn't do this already.

Comment: @Hammerite ahhhh... because, tsql has not such syntax, you can't write like you do in question

Comment: @Backs Add info that IIF works with SQL Server 2012+

Answer (score 2):

You can change `NULL` values with `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`:

<kbd>**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/375003)**</kbd>

```
select id, val, ISNULL(val, 0) as val_null
from MyTable;
```

or:

```
select id, val, COALESCE(val, 0) as val_null
from MyTable;
```

or

```
select id, val, CASE 
                 WHEN val IS NULL THEN 0
                 ELSE val
               END as val_null
from MyTable;
```

**Explanation:**

You cannot use `IS NULL` [predicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189523.aspx) directly in `SELECT`:

> Is an expression that evaluates to TRUE, FALSE, or UNKNOWN. Predicates
>   are used in the search condition of WHERE clauses and HAVING clauses,
>   the join conditions of FROM clauses, and other constructs where a
>   Boolean value is required.

Use `ISNULL`/`COALESCE` function instead. Or wrap predicate with `CASE`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't simply `SELECT val IS NULL` is because there's no implicit coercion from this type of expression (a predicate) to a value. For that matter, it's no different from `SELECT val > 10`. You can see the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189523(v=sql.110).aspx), where it explicitly sais:

> *(Predicates, including IS [NOT] NULL...)* Is an expression that evaluates to TRUE, FALSE, or UNKNOWN. Predicates are used in the search condition of WHERE clauses and HAVING clauses, the join conditions of FROM clauses, and other constructs where a Boolean value is required.

When you want to use a predicate to select a value you should be explicit about it, for example, using `IIF()`:

```
SELECT id, val, IIF(val IS NULL , 'True', 'False') AS val_null 
FROM MyTable;
```